# In ASP.NET save textarea to html without using database

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax

In ASP.NET Core I have a home page that I would like to add a 'notes' section to, that anyone can append to. On the page I have this

```
<p id="noteSection"></p>

<textarea row="6" cols="66" id="note" value="message"></textarea>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success" onclick="SaveNotes()">Save</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SaveNotes() {
        var value = document.getElementById('note');
        $('#noteSection').text(value);
    }
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I allow for any user to input a note into the text area, click save, and have that text save into the `<p></p>` indefinitely? I want it to save even if a user logs out it will still be appended in the html upon relogging in? I would prefer not to have to create a table for this,.

Comment: What I can think is, either you write your data into a text file on the server via ajax call and then load it for every user, or you should regenerate html page that you are using it is the only way you can do it without involving database in it. Or perhaps, if someone comes up with a better idea and approach.

Comment: What if I saved the string into a variable, somehow saving it in the controller or an ajax call, allow the `textarea` to append it, and then display it in the `<p></p>` tags

Comment: That variable would only be accessible to that specific user, not for every user. Perhaps, you should study about `Application Variables` that are common throughout the app.

Comment: I ended up just creating a new database like people were saying to do, and basically only allow the Create action to be accessed if `.Count() == 0`, else just edit, this way I will only have one value in the entire table that can be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you create a table for it tho? If you want to keep it forever you need a away to persist the values. <strike>The only other option I can think about would be to use localstorage or cookies</strike>

Comment: OP wants that anyone should be able to append, in which scenario, using cookies and localstorage is never going to work because it is client's browser specific thing.

Comment: I am just trying to keep my tables to a minimum, also I am trying think of it as a whiteboard style. So other users can go in and delete old notes, add new ones etc. Just like a whiteboard it can be erased and rewritten

Comment: What if I saved string variable in the html itself, and somehow saved that variable either in a controller or ajax? Would that also require some cookie or database usage to keep that variable and continuously re write to it?

Comment: I don't know how you could save a variable in the html tbh. If you create a variable and then assign a value, the moment you refresh the page, it will disappear

Comment: Okay maybe I could try creating a variable in a controller, and passing that variable to ajax and passing that into a `span` tag or something? I will see